# Kotlin/Android: setOnItemClickListener no se ejecuta con una lista de checkbox

Tags: android, kotlin, listview

Tengo un activity que se crea con una lista(ListView) de checkbox pero cuando selecciono alguno de estos checkbox el evento `setOnItemClickListener` no responde, puse un breakpoint para debuggear lo que pasaba pero nunca entra al bloque del clic, como si no lo tomara en cuenta:

```
val allList = buyQueryDB.getBuyList(id_list)
        if(!allList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            for(row in allList){
                val elementList = buyElement(row.key,row.value)
                pendingList.add(elementList)
            }
            adapter = buyListPendingAdapter(BaseDB.CONTEXT,pendingList)
            lstNewList.adapter = adapter

            lstNewList.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
                println("selected: $position")
                // Proceso
            }
        }
```

Puse un println() y un Toast para ver que se ejecutara pero no se ejecutan estas lineas.
Intente con estas variantes del `setOnItemClickListener` por ejemplo intente referenciar antes el objeto ListView para poder usar el evento:

```
var lstPendingList = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.lstNewList) as ListView
            lstPendingList.setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
                println("selected: $position")
            })
```

Y esta otra alternativa que encontré por aquí:

```
lstNewList.setOnItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{ parent, view, position, id ->
println("selected: $position")
}
```

No obtengo ningún error ni excepciones nada, solo no se ejecuta el código cuando selecciono alguno. Tengo otro Activity similar que funciona bien, misma estructura la única diferencia es que en este incorpore un checkbox.
Intente tambien poner el evento al objeto checkBox `checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener...` pero sobre este si obtenía un error de objeto "`NullPointerException`"

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener (android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
```

Este es el adapter de ListView:

```
class buyListPendingAdapter(val mcontext:Context,val elements:List<buyElement>):ArrayAdapter<buyElement>(mcontext, 0, elements){
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val layout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.buy_list_pending,parent,false)
        val element = elements[position]
        layout.chkPending.text = element.name
        // Otros Objetos
        return layout
    }
}
```

Comment: Muestra tu Adapter, si alguna vista se queda con un estado sucio, debes limpiarlas. Por ejemplo si no se muestran los checkbox activos / seleccionado luego de seleccionarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Asegura que la lista de checkbox tenga definido los atributos:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

y en el contenedor de esta vista:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

      <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Eso soluciono la ejecución del código dentro del evento `setOnItemClickListener `, pero ahora el problema es que no se muestran los checkbox activos, siempre se quedan los cuadros como si no se hubieran activado.

Comment: Como esta definido tu layout?

Comment: `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">`